# How to identify system objects when viewing list of SQL Server database objects?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-schema

I'm trying to list all the stored procedures from all the databases on my server, and I can't seem to filter out system objects reliably. I was using:

```
SELECT *
  FROM sysobjects
 WHERE id > 100
```

Which seems to work fine in every database except MSDB, which is full of a ton of stored procs with normal-looking IDs, but they're system stored procs. As far as I can tell, there's no way for me to filter out system stored procs using any of the values in the sysobjects table - does anybody else know of a value that can be used to filter?

They're all marked as type="P", which means it's a stored proc, but there seems to be no flag to specify if it's a system stored proc or a user one. I can use the sys.objects view and filter for "IsMsShipped=0", but I'd like something that also works on SQL 2000, so I'd prefer to use the older views (like sysobjects) if it's possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works on my SQL Server 2008 R2 install. I don't see much at all except for user databases

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
   sys.objects
WHERE
   OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id, 'IsMSShipped') = 0
```

You can change [sys.objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324.aspx) to say, sys.tables and it still works, or use the "type" column to filter. Or use OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id, 'IsProcedure') etc.

Note: it's sys.objects in SQL Server 2005+

Note 2: [OBJECTPROPERTY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276849%28SQL.80%29.aspx) will work for SQL Server 2000 too:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
   sysobjects
WHERE
   OBJECTPROPERTY(id, 'IsMSShipped') = 0
```

Comment: This may be what I have to go with, as I'd noticed that property in the newer system view, but I'm holding out hope that there's an easily-accessible property that works in 2000 as well.

Comment: er...  OBJECTPROPERTY is in SQL Server 2000 too http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276849(SQL.80).aspx

Comment: Hmm - for sure it is, and I just confirmed that my script still runs on a 2000 server. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think @gbn is right so I believe `SELECT *  FROM sysobjects WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(id, 'IsMSShipped') = 0` will work in 2000. Right?

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server 2005 and higher

```
SELECT
  SCHEMA_NAME(obj.schema_id) AS schema_name,
  obj.name AS proc_name
FROM
  sys.procedures obj WITH(NOLOCK)
ORDER BY
  schema_name,
  proc_name
```

SQL Server 2000

```
SELECT
  USER_NAME(obj.uid) AS user_name,
  obj.name AS proc_name,
FROM
  sysobjects obj WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE
  (obj.status & 0x80000000) = 0
  AND RTRIM(obj.xtype) IN ('P', 'RF')
ORDER BY
  user_name,
  proc_name
```

Answer (score 1):

In certain SQL Versions (I don't know in what version this started), there is at least one scenario where a database can contain system objects that have an **IsMSShipped** property that is set to false.

With the ability to add database diagrams to a database, the follow objects are often added after an initial install, at the point when a user, say, in SSMS, initiates a request to create database diagrams.

[image]

I would modify the previously accepted answer to be as follows:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
   sysobjects obj
WHERE
   OBJECTPROPERTY(obj.id, 'IsMSShipped') = 0
AND (CAST(
    CASE
        WHEN (
            SELECT 
                major_id 
            FROM 
                sys.extended_properties 
            WHERE 
                major_id = obj.id and 
                minor_id = 0 and 
                class = 1 and 
                name = N'microsoft_database_tools_support') 
            IS NOT NULL then 1
        ELSE 0
    END as bit)) = 0
```

This additional sub-query was take from code executed by SSMS when getting a list of (non-)system objects.